# Why do I need to change ownership to daemon for plugins to update?

Tags: wordpress, xampp, file-permissions

I recently installed Wordpress using XAMPP local testing environment.

When I tried to run updates for my plugins, it asked me for FTP credentials and would not go any further.

I ended up running the following command which solved the issue:
sudo chown -R daemon /mysite/

Could someone explain why I would need to do this ?

When I ran the command ls -l /mysite/ before I did anything, it showed the user and group as me:me but when I ran the command:
sudo chown -R me:me /mysite/

it made no difference.

mysite permissions were set to 755 before I changed ownership.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The ftp credentials you can solve by adding

`define( 'FS_METHOD', 'direct' );`

to wp-config.php, at the very end.

As to your other problem, I'struggling with the same right now. What works (sort of) for me is to set the entire site to

```
sudo chown -hR daemon:deamon /opt/lampp/htdocs/yoursite
```

Now you can install plugins.

change to

```
 sudo chown -hR me:deamon /opt/lampp/htdocs/yoursite
```

to work on the files. For every change you have to do that.

It's not the right way to work, but the best bad solution I can find so far.